# Industry Name For This Image Setup?

Tags: website-design, style-identification

Wondering if there's an industry known name for this very common three column image setup below header banners. It's seen on almost every site nowadays so I assume it has coined a name by now?

[image]

Comment: Though it doesn't answer your question about terminology; it could just be that so many sites use Bootstrap or a derivative and they all look the same because of that: http://adventurega.me/bootstrap/?utm_source=designernews

Answer (score 3):

Organizing information into small bite sized pieces is nothing new, it's a  prudential tactic that arises from our inherent desire to segment information for readability.

As far as an industry term, the closest would be "info boxes". Further specifying that these particular info boxes would be center justified and using circular masks to crop the associated images.

[image: Info Boxes example]

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a specific word to describe the layout but I have seen people say **Icon Box** when they are defining this layout. You will primarily see Icon Box said when looking at Wordpress Shortcodes.

Comment: I have seen "Icon Box" used in Wordpress Visual Designer only. In my experience, no one would know what you meant if you said "Let's put icon boxes on this web page"